# Left-invariant vector fields on the unit circle

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a Lie group $G$, a vector field $X$ on $G$ is said to be *left-invariant* if 
\begin{align*}
\left(\ell_g  \right)_{*,h}(X_h) = X_{gh}
\end{align*}
for all $g,h\in G$, where $\ell_g:G\to G$, $\ell_g(x)=gx$, is *the left multiplication by $g$*. A point that is worth noting is that there exists a $1-1$ correspondence between the tangent space $T_{e}G$ of $G$ at the identity $e$ and $L(G)$, the vector space of all left-invariant vector fields on $G$, given by 
\begin{align*}
(\phi(X_e))_g = (\ell_g)_{*,e}X_e.
\end{align*}

Restricting our talk to the unit circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}^\times$, I proved that the tangent space $T_{1}S^1$ can be identified with the vertical line $x=0$ so that each tangent vector $X_1 \in T_{1}S^1$ is a pair $(0,v)$ for some $v\in \mathbb{R}$, and that the tangent space $T_{z_0}S^1$ for any $z_0\in S^1$ is identified with the left-multiplication of the vertical line $x=0$ by $z_0$; that is,
\begin{align*}
T_{z_0}S^1 = \left\lbrace z_0 .(0,v): v\in \mathbb{R}  \right\rbrace.
\end{align*}
However, I failed in finding the left-invariant vector fields on the unit circle. Would the results I got help in accomplishing my purpose ?.

I need help please, I appreciate any help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753376/left-invariant-vector-fields-on-the-circle-s1